# best way to implement css 100% width by ignoring parent div padding

Tags: html, css

For the following DOM, only child3 should be having a 100% width ignoring/overriding the padding of the parent container, and the rest child elements should have 100% width while also respecting the padding

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
  <div class="child4"></div>
  <div class="child5"></div>
  <div class="child6"></div>
</div>
```

constraints for container's CSS

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

what is the best way to implement the same?
one way to achieve this is:

```
.child3 {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -40px; /*to offset parent container's padding*/
}
```

Here is what my code does:

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 40px;
}
.child3 {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -40px; /*to offset parent container's padding*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
  <div class="child4"></div>
  <div class="child5"></div>
  <div class="child6"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a rough diagram showing what I would like it to do[image: .]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Comment: Or, in your specific case, why don't you use 40px margins (horizontally) for all the elements besides for the ones that should touch the wrappers edges??

Answer (score 1):

- If you wish to be more dynamic, then use of css variable will make your code effective
- we use `--padding` variable here. to change values of variable, just change it in `:root`.
- I have used a 1px border to show difference(black is parent,red is children)
- The formula i used for width is,
  `total possible length when not parent padding is ignored + twice the padding(becuase padding acts on both side) - 1px(which is border)`
  and for margin is `-padding`

The code snippet:

```css
:root {
  --padding: 40px;
}
.container {
    width: 300px;
    padding: var(--padding);
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.child3 {
    width: calc(100% + (2*var(--padding)) - 1px);
    margin-left: calc(0px - var(--padding)); /*to offset parent container's padding*/
}
.container *{
border: 1px solid red;
height:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
  <div class="child4"></div>
  <div class="child5"></div>
  <div class="child6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write it like this (when I see the layout)...
Excuse me if I'm wrong because I delete the padding and add margins to the divs instead and match the image you added to your post.

See the momment of @Roko C. Buljan

I don't know if you want to do this, so let me know if it looks OK for You or if I must delete my answer.

It seems less tricky AMO.

```css
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .container {
        width: 300px;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        border:1px solid #000000;
    }
    .container div{
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        height:20px;
        border:1px solid #000000;
    }
    .container .child3 {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        border:1px solid #ff0000;
    }
    .container .child6 {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="child1">My content 1</div>
      <div class="child2">My content 2</div>
      <div class="child3">My content 3</div>
      <div class="child4">My content 4</div>
      <div class="child5">My content 5</div>
      <div class="child6">My content 6 (last div)</div>
</div>
```